# How do I create a cascading drop down link in Excel?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to create a cascading drop down link in Excel 2010.

My requirement is when we click when we select any color from dropdown list related color fruits will displayed beside.

Comment: Please clarify your question: What beside means for you: Do you want to change entries in the same list, our do you want those changed cakes in another column? Please also post some screenshots to show how your sheet / form looks like.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe what you want to do is simply **data filtering**. This functionality is available in main spreadsheet programs and I will explain how to use it on an example.

Plants are listed in a table:

[image]

For each plant, it is written its type (fruit, vegetable...) in column "type" and its color in column "color".

Select the header items and apply "auto-filter" on them:

[image]

Each header item now have a drop-down button to filter data according to one or more value(s).

[image]

To do that, click on the drop-down button and set up your filter as needed. For instance, filter red color only.

[image]

Your can see now that only the red plants appear in the table.

[image]

The screenshots are from LibreOffice Calc on Linux Ubuntu, but you should be able to adapt it to Microsoft Excel on Windows 7 really easily.